# WorkBookQuery user-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am trying to load a query I have in windows clipboard from powerquery via Macro. But I can't test it because I don't have a reference and I don't know how to guess which one is it:

```
Sub readClipboard()
'Tools -> References -> Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
'of you will get a "Compile error: user-defined type not defined"
Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
Dim S As String
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Dim qry As WorkbookQuery

Set currentSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)

DataObj.GetFromClipboard
S = DataObj.GetText

Set qry = ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add("Prueba", S, "Nose")

With currentSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & Query.Name _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdDefault
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & Query.Name & "]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Needs a reference to the "MSForms" library.  If you temporarily add a userform to your VBA project then the reference will be added automatically.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but i have already had that problem, it is not complaining about that, but what it does not recognize is WoorkBookQuery, not MsForms.DataObject

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1   Are you using Excel 2016 ?

Comment: Nope, im using office 2013

Comment: I also understood that object was introduced in Excel 2016.  Oddly, the doco says 2013 so now I'm confused: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt575010.aspx

Comment: Easiest way is to get 2 string variables, one to hold the query name, one to hold the formula, once you have that, then use the add method you have there. If you want to reference a query, simply make a table, create a query from it, and then reference it, then check that query's formula, you'll see it just points to that query, once you have that, you can use the little code snippet and just use a find and replace to make new queries...